# .htaccess not showing rest of my URL after RedirectMatch

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

Thanks for taking a look at my question, which is:

I'm trying to replace a string in a Woocommerce product page the structure is as follows:

**www.mysite.com/es/producto/niche/something**

I'm trying to change this to:

**www.mysite.com/es/product/niche/something**

Basically changing the string "producto" to "product"

I thought of using RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 /es/producto(.*) /es/product/(.*)$
```

but I'm just getting redirected to **www.mysite.com/es/product/(.*)$**

any insight into this would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /es/producto/(.*) /es/product/$1`

Comment: doesn't work... but thanks anyways, I really appreciate it.

Comment: So try this: Redirect 301 /es/producto(.*) /es/product$1